# What kind of microphone is this and how do I use/bias it?

Tags: amplifier, audio, identification, microphone

I am designing the mic input for a ham radio chip I bought, a [DRA818V](http://www.dorji.com/docs/data/DRA818V.pdf).

Someone gave me an old Kenwood ham radio mic and said I can use that mic for my circuit.  The mic element is shown below:

[image: Rear of microphone element]

[image: Front of microphone element]

What kind of microphone is this and how can I use/bias it?

My LCR meter says it has 304 ohms of DC resistance.  It has 4.653 mH at 1 kHz of inductance.  I have an oscilloscope to use to complete my circuit.  The mic input of my chip, the DRA818V, is not well described, so I will have to experiment to see what the chip "likes".  I expect I will have to make a small signal amp from an NPN transistor to feed the "mic in" of my chip.

My main question is: What is this mic and how do I use it?  If I can set it up and see it on my oscilloscope, I can experiment if I need to amplify it or not?

Comment: Well, a simple test would be to hook it up straight to a 'scope probe (nothing else - the two leads of the mic to the probe & ground clip) and see if any signal is registered when you yell at it.

Comment: @anrieff  I previously experimented with a circuit.  I supplied a few volts to the mic and used a capacitor between the positive line and the DRA818V mic in.  The chip did transmit audio over the air.  So, it does work.  I think I might not have to supply power to the mic.  It was not the best quality audio and needs adjusting.  I did connect the leads to the oscilloscope and have tried yelling at the mic.  The raw readings were in the milli volt range and, after yelling, departed form their average.  The average was really bouncing around at a few mv and hard to understand what best use is

Comment: I'd expect it is a dynamic microphone.  No bias.  Just connect it to the scope and whistle at it.  A dynamic microphone will put out a signal in the millivolt range.  Certainly no more than 100 millivolts.  Whistle because it makes a more identifiable signal than talking or yelling.  A whistle sound looks like a constant sine wave.  Voice is all wiggly and jiggly and hard to tell from noise if you don't know what you are looking at.  Set the scope to 1 millisecond per division, and the smallest voltage per division your scope has.

Comment: @JRE  It does appear to be a dynamic mic.  When I whistle in it, I see the noise on the scope change its appearance.  It is not a very clear shift on the scope, but seems to happen.  I plan to use an NPN transistor and amplify the signal.  I would like to see fairly large clear swings when I speak and feed it into my DRA818V.  There is no documentation I can find as to what oscillation range the signal should be in for the chip mic in..

Answer (score 1):

Now that it seems certain that you have a dynamic microphone, let's have a look at what your [DRA818V module](http://www.dorji.com/docs/data/DRA818V.pdf) needs at the microphone input.

On page 3 of the datasheet, there's a table of radio characteristics:

[image]

Down towards the bottom is this line:

> Sen_MOD  Modulation Sensitivity @1KHz at 2.5KHz Fdev.  10mV

That's telling you that a 10mV peak to peak signal applied to the microphone input will result in 2.5 kHz of deviation.  That's the maximum deviation when using a narrow channel.  It isn't clear if you need a stronger microphone signal for full modulation on a wide channel. (It also tells you that this specification is tested using a 1kHz audio test signal.)

What that means is that you need at most 20mV of microphone signal going into the DRA818V to get the maximum possible transmit deviation.  That means 20mV to get your spoken voice from the transmit side to maximum volume on the receive side.

What you need to do is to capture your spoken voice on the microphone with your oscilloscope, and measure its peak to peak voltage.  From that you figure out how much amplification you need to get to 20mV peak to peak.  That shouldn't be much, maybe a gain of 5 to 10.

If your microphone amplifier has too much gain then it will sound distorted on the receiving side, but you won't be breaking any regulations.  The transmitter will (should) clip  the transmit audio to keep your modulation within the allowed limits.

You might not need any amplifier at all for the microphone.  Just connect it straight to MIC_IN and ground and give it a try.  I expect the bias you mentioned in comments interfered with the microphone and caused the output to be too weak.

Comment: Sen_MOD was a major missing link in my understanding.  I can easily work on obtaining a gain of 5 to 10 and use my scope to get it perfectly in the range of 20 mV Pk to Pk.

Comment: As I said, try it with just the microphone connected.  The microphone might supply enough signal as is.

Comment: Earlier I had tried connecting the mic directly.  I remember being underwhelmed with the level of loudness I had to speak to hear something on another test radio close by.  I don't remember hearing much, if anything on the other radio.  The tests could have been performed better, but I decided that it needed amplification since I should ideally speak normal tone close to it.  I then decided to make an amplifier circuit and adjust it to what sounds decent on the air, while looking for more exacting specs of what the module ideally needs.  Thanks so much for your help